# Compare two columns and if not equal, set them equal based off a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am creating a query to pull a bunch of information for ID, date, status etc. I have pretty much everything done besides this part. I am trying to compare two variables (which I will call here `S_End` and `P_EndDate`) and if `P_EndDate` is AFTER `S_End`, then I need to set `S_End = P_EndDate`.

Both of these variables have dates stored in the format: `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`.

Here is what I have so far for this specific part of my query, just to narrow down to the few entries where this would be applied to:

```sql
SELECT status, ID, SStart, S_End, P_EndDate, comment FROM myTable
WHERE SStart IS NOT NULL AND STATUS = 'NOT DONE' AND S_End <> P_EndDate
```

This works and gets me the few entries I need where `P_EndDate` is before/after `S_End` but I am really not sure how to compare/set `S_End = P_EndDate`. I have tried using an `IF` statement similar to

```sql
IF S_End > P_EndDate 
   BEGIN 
      S_End  = P_EndDate 
   END
ELSE 
   BEGIN
      S_End  = S_End  
   END
```

but I keep getting syntax errors or a message saying unexpected syntax next to `IF`. I have tried using `CAST` to convert both `S_End` and `P_EndDate` to just `YYYY/MM/DD` and then compare but still no luck. I feel this is something easy that I should know but I am not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Maybe because `S_End` is not a variable name.  Are these variables, or are you trying to use columns in an `IF` statement?

Comment: Just use a `CASE` expression `CASE WHEN S_End > P_EndDate THEN P_EndDate ELSE S_End END` Put that in your `SELECT`

Comment: @dougp Yes my bad. I am a noobie to this. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Variables start with an at "@" sign. These look like columns. If you are wanting to set the columns then...

```
UPDATE myTable
SET S_End = P_EndDate
WHERE S_End > P_EndDate
```

If you don't want to change the data, you just want your query to show P_EndDate in those cases, then use a case statement:

```
SELECT status, ID, SStart, S_End = CASE
   WHEN S_End > P_EndDate THEN P_EndDate
   ELSE S_End
   END, P_EndDate, comment FROM myTable
WHERE SStart IS NOT NULL AND STATUS = 'NOT DONE' AND S_End <> P_EndDate
```

If you really want variables, then you need to declare them and set their values.

Comment: Yes I got confused. Thank you! Accidentally overrode the data haha but thankfully I know the exact record so I was able to change it back to what it should be. Thank you again!